# Transitive verb for 'feeling inferior'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a transitive verb for 'feeling inferior'.

Example:

I was *inferiorised* by his burly figure.

Of course *inferiorised* is not a real word and it's just a placeholder for a word I'm looking for.

Comment: Patronized, perhaps.  Put down, dissed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[***belittle***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/belittle.html#C0-6) could be an option, but that would imply that the person has the intention to make you feel inferior.
However, in the context that you gave, I think [***intimidated***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/intimidated.html) is the best option:

> I was ***intimidated*** by his burly figure.

Comment: Intimidated fits the bill.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *humble*, which *Cambridge Dictionary* defines as—

> to make someone understand that they are not as important or special as they thought:

*He was humbled by the child's generosity.*

*The world champion was humbled (= unexpectedly defeated) by an unknown outsider in last night's race.*